# Iterate through part of a map in C++

Tags: c++

How do I iterate through only part of a map in C++? My end goal is to have multiple threads iterate through their part of the map and compute some values. The map's type is `std::map<std::string, std::vector<double> >`

Comment: How about `std::for_each()`?

Comment: Which part of the map do you want to iterate through? Yes, it can be done, and yes I know how. But unless I know your criteria for how to select a part of the map to iterate through, I can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: @jalf : so if I have 4 threads then each thread will go through 1/4th of the map size

Comment: Is your problem iterating between the various parts or determining which iterators in the map are at the bounds of each quarter?

Comment: @AndyProwl: but how does that help iterate through only a part of the map? so for example I want to start from position 25 and iterate only until position 35 then how would I do that?

Comment: wait, so you need to iterate through every vector in the map as well?

Comment: @zacaj: yes but that vector is the value of the key:

again the map definition is: `std::map <std::string, std::vector<double> >`

Comment: Is there any reason why the quarters need to be iterated in order?  Why not just iterate through the whole map and push each vector to a worker thread?

Comment: I think the problem here is more about the OP not knowing how to get iterators to the bounds desired.

Comment: But the question is does he actually need to do that at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing it in C++11:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<double>> map_type;

void do_work(map_type::iterator b, map_type::iterator e)
{
    std::for_each(b, e, [] (map_type::value_type const& p) 
    {
        std::for_each(p.second.begin(), p.second.end(), [] (double d) 
        {
            /* Process an element of the vector... */
        });
    });
}

int main()
{
    map_type m;

    size_t s = m.size();
    int quarter = s / 4;
    auto i1 = m.begin();
    auto i2 = std::next(i1, quarter);
    auto i3 = std::next(i2, quarter);
    auto i4 = std::next(i3, quarter);
    auto i5 = m.end();

    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    futures.push_back(std::async(do_work, i1, i2));
    futures.push_back(std::async(do_work, i2, i3));
    futures.push_back(std::async(do_work, i3, i4));
    futures.push_back(std::async(do_work, i4, i5));

    for (auto& f : futures) { f.wait(); }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I got an idea, how about templatize that and create algo called something like parallel_foreach ?

Comment: Why is it always like that: when you get a good idea somebody else already implemented that?

Comment: @Slava: got to live with it :-)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Looks promising but whenever I try to use `std::next` it gives me an error saying next is not a part of std

Comment: @AndyProwl: I dont think so

Comment: @AndyProwl: ok so it worked thank you so much.

PS : I made changes when I compile. Something like this `g++ -std=c++0x -c filename.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split work by numbers evenly, then map probably not the best data structure. You would need to iterate over map and find iterators for particular positions. If you use container that provides random acces iterator like std::vector then you can just calculate iterators arithmetically.
If you want to do that alphabetically, then you can do something like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string,std::vector<double>> data;

void process( data::iterator beg, data::iterator end );
data dt;
{
   auto task1 = std::async( process, dt.begin(), dt.lower_bound( "n" ) );
   auto task2 = std::async( process, dt.lower_bound( "n" ), dt.end() );
}
```

assuming all strings are lowercase.